# Can't load custom CSS on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I am running Rails 3.2.8 and built an app which links to a custom CSS file and images. The custom CSS file is placed in my Assets/stylesheets folder and images are in Assets/images.

For some reason, the CSS and images don't load when I push the app to Heroku. The app generates a manifest.yml file which contains all the images and CSS file.

The CSS file is a customised version of Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Hope you guys can help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you putting the stylesheet in '/app/assets/stylesheets' and the images in '/app/assets/images'? Also, did you include the custom stylesheet in '/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can store images on heroku. You'll have to use something like amazone s3 bucket. And then link the ccs images to the amazone bucket

Comment: Actually, you can push assets images to Heroku just fine. It is just that if the program uploads images, they will be lost on the next restart and not available to other web processes.